# Undefined index with PHP sessions

Tags: php, session, if-statement, header

I'm new to PHP and am even more of a beginner when it comes to sessions. I have my index.php page, which is where users can register and login. The forms are posting to validate.php and loginvalidate.php pages, respectively for registering and logging in.

I have these errors on index.php when I load it:

1) Notice: Undefined index: registered
2) Notice: Undefined index: neverused

I have tried modifying my text in many ways but I never got to solve the errors.

Index.php

```
    <?php
            if ($_SESSION['registered'] != NULL){
                echo $_SESSION['registered'];                   
            }
            if ($_SESSION['badlogin'] != NULL){
                echo $_SESSION['badlogin'];
            }
            if ($_SESSION['neverused'] != NULL) {
                echo $_SESSION['neverused'];                    
            }
    ?>
```

Validate.php (after submitting register form)

```
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {  //IF THERE IS A PASSWORD FOR THAT EMAIL IN DATABASE
    $_SESSION['registered'] = "Email is already registered.";
    mysqli_close($db_handle);
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Loginvalidate.php (after submitting login form)

```
if ($numrows!=0)  //IF THERE IS A PASSWORD FOR THAT EMAIL IN THE DATABASE
{
  if ($row['password'] == $password) {  //IF THE PASSWORD MATCHES USER INPUT
      header('Location: homepage.php');
      echo "lol";
      exit();
  }
  else{
    $_SESSION['badlogin'] = "Email/password combination not valid.";
    mysqli_close($db_handle);
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
  } 
}
else {  //THERE IS NO PASSWORD FOR THAT EMAIL, SO THAT EMAIL IS NOT REGISTERED
    $_SESSION['neverused'] = "Email is not registered.";
    mysqli_close($db_handle);
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Okay so my script does what it is intended to do. The only thing that I can't solve is these session errors. Do you see any misuse of sessions? Of course, I have started the sessions in all of my .php files.

Also, note that I am aware that there is no protection from hackers. This is only for a future prototype that won't contain any important data.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason for these errors is that you're trying to read an array key that doesn't exist. The [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function is there so you can test for this. Something like the following for each element will work a treat; there's no need for null checks as you never assign null to an element:

```
// check that the 'registered' key exists
if (isset($_SESSION['registered'])) {

    // it does; output the message
    echo $_SESSION['registered'];

    // remove the key so we don't keep outputting the message
    unset($_SESSION['registered']);
}
```

You could also use it in a loop:

```
$keys = array('registered', 'badlogin', 'neverused');

//iterate over the keys to test
foreach($keys as $key) {

    // test if $key exists in the $_SESSION global array
    if (isset($_SESSION[$key])) {

        // it does; output the value
        echo $_SESSION[$key];

        // remove the key so we don't keep outputting the message
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're getting undefined index errors, you might try making sure that your indexes are set before you try comparing the values.  See the documentation for the isset function here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

```
if (isset($_SESSION['registered']))
  if ($_SESSION['registered'] != NULL){
      echo $_SESSION['registered'];                   
  }
}
if (isset($_SESSION['badlogin']))
  if ($_SESSION['badlogin'] != NULL){
      echo $_SESSION['badlogin'];
  }
}
if (isset($_SESSION['neverused']))
  if ($_SESSION['neverused'] != NULL) {
      echo $_SESSION['neverused'];                    
  }
}
```

Comment: It works! I was trying to check if the session variables were set with if ($_SESSION['x'] != NULL   instead of with if (isset($_SESSION['x'])). I had good logic, but wrong syntax. Thank you very much.