# store "bad login" in session or url?

Tags: php, session, authentication

When a user tries to login om my website, I publish the form to `/login`
the login script redirects if there is no email-password match, to `/login/tried-to-login`
And then I use "whatever comes after `login/` for logic on what to show on the page (for example "Please try again").

I just read in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731693/undefined-index-with-php-sessions) about a person using sessions for storing such details:

```
$_SESSION['bad_login'] = ...
```

I would perhaps use 'status'
`$_SESSION['status'] = 'login failed', $_SESSION['status'] = 'no password'`.

Is sessions that a better way to do it? To always send the user to just /login ? Which one is better/cleaner code? I think I'd argue that including the message in the url is user friendly? What would gains be from keeping it in Session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say a user tries to login, and the login fails for bad password.  You could redirect them to `login.php?status=bad+password` or you could set `$_SESSION['status']='bad password';` and then redirect to login.php, and display the message.

So what's the difference?

1. The main and most obvious one is, with the parameter method (i.e. `login.php?status=bad+password`) someone can go to that URL anytime and see the message without actually even trying to login.  With the session method, you can only see the message after you actually tried to login.
2. Obviously, also, anytime you do something like a `echo $_REQUEST['status'];` you are printing user input directly without validating.  The user could inject some HTML in there or something.   But if you were setting a session variable with a *hardcoded* message, it would be safe to do `echo $_SESSION['status'];` without having to worry about validation. (Never put user input directly in the session without sanitizing/validating.)
3. With the session method, you can drop the display of the message on refresh of the login page.

   ```
     if(isset($_SESSION['status']))
     {
       echo $_SESSION['status']; 
       unset($_SESSION['status']);
     }
   ```

Now on refresh, you won't display the message a second time since you erased the value after printing it.  But with the URL parameter method, each refresh of the page will show the message again, despite the fact that the user has not actually tried to login again!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest - Storing message in the URL is a better way, just like facebook does [like this](https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1)

Comment: Facebook also left its login page without SSL for years.  They aren't really the guys to be following for best practices. And its no excuse that they were a startup: You can buy a basic SSL cert for $150.

Comment: Yes I agree with your comment but I believe using session is not the best practices :)

Comment: Smart! Why didn't I think about entering wrong credentials for some other services! Will try!