# Undefined index in php function

Tags: php, arrays, string, forms, function

The following function generates a success message every time after a form is submitted successfully:

```
function CreateNotice($notice,$type='notification')
{
    $_SESSION['Message'][] =  array($type,$notice);  
}
function DisplayNotice()
{
    $str = '';
    if(count($_SESSION['Message']) > 0) ------>------>----->Line 85
    {
        for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['Message']);$i++)
        {
          $str.="<div class='".$_SESSION['Message'][$i][0]."Message left'>".$_SESSION['Message'][$i][1]."</div>";
        }
        unset($_SESSION['Message']);
        return $str;
    }   
}
```

It produces the following notice whenever the page is opened in the browser.

```
Notice: Undefined index: Message in /home/user/public_html/dir/subdir/test.php on line 85
```

Any idea?

Comment: do u have session_start() before the function call ?

Comment: You are running `CreateNotice()` first right ? Because if you run `DisplayNotice()` first , you will run into this notice.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731693/undefined-index-with-php-sessions][1]

Check out this link you might find right solution.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731693/undefined-index-with-php-sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line on top of your script (if it is not there already)

```
session_start(); // Starts the session so you can make use of $_SESSION
```

And add these lines in `DisplayNotice()`.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Message']))    // check this condition only is session is set
{
    if(count($_SESSION['Message']) > 0) 
    {
    ......................
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zarthus & Jenz , it seems that, if error reporting is turned on, all the undefined variables require a check using `isset` function in order to avoid undefined index or variable. There is no other way to avoid these notice unless error reporting is off.

Comment: @SilentPond, the error triggers regardless, error_reporting just displays the error for your view.

Comment: @Zarthus , I understand that but it helps you identify the conflicts in codes that really exist because of improper grammar in programming language. For example, if I say you, `"Me and you go there"` you shall understand me but in fact grammatically it's not correct. That's only it.

Comment: @SilentPond that doesn't make it any less wrong. You should fix errors in your code our may come across nasty side effects. It's true that your error is a notice. But it is still an error that should not have occurred in the first place. I **really** suggest that you solve ANY error as it comes up. It is not an excuse to not fix something this easy, even if the end user does not get to see it anyways. -- coding is a more precise task than grammar. The side effects therefore are also much more significant. Example: $_POST['password'] is not set on login, but your script logs the user in anyways

Answer (score 2):

The error is simple: You're accessing something from an array that is not defined.

For example,

```
$a = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
$b = $a[4]; // 4 does not exist. (0, 1, 2, 3 do)
```

To solve the error, verify it is set by with an if check using [`isset`](https://www.php.net/isset).

For example, like this.

```
$a = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
if (isset($a[4])) { $b = $a[4]; } // 4 doesn't exists, 
   // so we move over to the else condition 
   // (which is optional, but otherwise we get the issue that B is not defined). 
   // Once again, 0, 1, 2, 3 do exist of this array
else $b = false;
```

In addition to this, I suggest you look into the [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) syntax for looping over arrays, but that isn't related to your issue.

Also, because this error is triggered, it *likely* means that you're not calling your function `CreateNotice` before calling `DisplayNotice`

Answer (score 1):

use `**isset**` in your if condition in function DisplayNotice(){...}

```
if(count(isset($_SESSION['Message'])) > 0)
```

Comment: it doesn't eliminate undefined index though you code looks logical to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code  on top of page

error_reporting(0);