# Data stored in Session but when fetch in other php file some objects is null

Tags: php, session

On the original where I stored the data in session array, all data are complete when I fetch it but when I call that session on the other some data is null or undefined.

I don't know what I'm going to do, please help

Edit:   In original file

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("Select p.start_date,p.end_date,dfp.id,dfp.product_id
      dfp.type,dfp.quantity_required,dfp.less,pd.unit,pd.name
      from promo p
      inner join discounts_free_products dfp                        
      on p.id=dfp.promo_id                        
      inner join products pd                        
      on dfp.product_id=pd.id                       
      where DATE(p.end_date) >= DATE(NOW()) 
");
$query->execute();
$count=0;
$queryresult_set=array();
$queryresult_set=$query->fetchAll();
$count=count($queryresult_set); 
$_SESSION['COUNT_PROMO']= $count;
$_SESSION["PROMO_PRODUCTS"]=$queryresult_set;
```

In other php file

```
foreach($_SESSION["PROMO_PRODUCTS"] as $result) { 
    $pc_list[] = $result["product_id"]; 
    $d_id=$result['id']; 
}
```

error:Undefined index: product_id

Comment: please share your code ?

Comment: Add your code in question not in comments...

Comment: If @Abdulla 's answear was correct, please make sure to mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP 5 Session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

> A **session is started with the `session_start()` function.**

Session Create

```
<?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
    $_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

To retrieve session on another page

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
    // Echo session variables that were set on previous page
    echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
    echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["favanimal"] . ".";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to add `session_start();` at the beginning of your file(s). This was the most common issue when I started. But without your code, nobody here can help you.

Edit:
Are you sure you have: 
**original.php**

```
session_start();
$query = $dbh->prepare("Select p.start_date,p.end_date,dfp.id,dfp.product_id
          dfp.type,dfp.quantity_required,dfp.less,pd.unit,pd.name
          from promo p
          inner join discounts_free_products dfp                        
          on p.id=dfp.promo_id                        
          inner join products pd                        
          on dfp.product_id=pd.id                       
          where DATE(p.end_date) >= DATE(NOW()) 
");
$query->execute();
$count=0;
$queryresult_set=array();
$queryresult_set=$query->fetchAll();
$count=count($queryresult_set); 
$_SESSION['COUNT_PROMO']= $count;
$_SESSION["PROMO_PRODUCTS"]=$queryresult_set;
```

And in **other.php**

```
session_start();
foreach($_SESSION["PROMO_PRODUCTS"] as $result) { 
        $pc_list[] = $result["product_id"]; 
        $d_id=$result['id']; 
}
```

**Edit**
Try:

```
session_start();
foreach($_SESSION["PROMO_PRODUCTS"] as $result) {
    if (isset($_SESSION["PROMO_PRODUCTS"]))
       if ($_SESSION["PROMO_PRODUCTS"] != NULL){
          $pc_list[] = $result["product_id"]; 
          $d_id=$result['id']; 
          echo $_SESSION["PROMO_PRODUCTS"];                   
       }
    }
}
```

Maybe you have the cookie but miss to fill it somewhere else. This is from `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731693/undefined-index-with-php-sessions">here</a>`.