# PHP session is not setting

Tags: php, session

I cannot understand why the PHP session is not working. It just simply won't set the session... How can I fix it?

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    session_name('dfm_session');
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['dfm_session'])){
        echo "yes";
    }
    else{
        echo "no";
    }
?>
```

Comment: first call session_start function then set $_SESSION['dfm_session'] = "some value"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data stored in Session but when fetch in other php file some objects is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836536/data-stored-in-session-but-when-fetch-in-other-php-file-some-objects-is-null)

Comment: `session_name()` sets the session name, it does not set a session variable with that key.

Comment: Yay they deleted their awful answers

Answer (score 0):

Like jeroin and filip said, you are trying to check if the session variable `dfm_session` exists which it doesn't. So change your `if` statement to this:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE
```

Or set that session value:

```
 $_SESSION['dfm_session'] = "some value")
```

Comment: He is starting the session right it's just his if statement