# How to access SESSION variables throughout PHP files?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

file1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$email = $_POST['email'];   
$password = $_POST['pass'];  

$_SESSION["email"] = $email;  
$_SESSION["pass"] = $password;  

//echo $_SESSION["email"];
header("location:file2.php");
?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$email = $_SESSION["email"];

echo $_SESSION["email"];
?>
```

I want to display the email the user logged in with. The error says "Undefined index email" at the second line in file2.php. Everywhere I've looked says to put session_start() at the top of every file, and to create the session in file1.php, then access it via line 2 of file2.php.

The only thing I can think that is making this not work is that this is not using HTML. I have an android app where the user enters their email and password. My app hands off the credentials to file1.php. I know it hands off correctly because if I uncomment line 6 of file1.php, the echo response works correctly. It for some reason, will not echo in file2.php.

The reason I need this to work is because I want to be able to use the email session variable in any php file (for logging out, display info, etc), and if I can't get it working in this simple example I will have no where to go.

Comment: `I have an android app where the user enters their email and password. My app hands off the credentials to file1.php` Does the app equally access file2.php then, or are you doing that some other way?

Comment: No the app does not directly access file2.php. That's why I want to be able to do this simple example because I need to every php page to know which email is currently logged in for other querying purposes. The app accesses certain individual php pages for different things, but I need to be able to query the database based on the email that was entered in file1.php.

Answer (score 0):

There are several similar questions on the site (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731693/undefined-index-with-php-sessions)). They suggest to use the `isset` method to ensure your session variable is available.

In your case, it could be added before the `header` call in file1.php, so

```
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    header("location:file2.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sessions in PHP by default are cookie based, your APP don't use cookies, you need to implement another method session like a self generate token against a database, maybe use a REST framework.

Another solution can be emulate the cookies with headers but I don't know if that is possible in Android

Answer (score 0):

Session works by cookie support, does your android app's request class supports this ?

It seems your client sends request to file1.php then server responses with session id in cookie, then your application redirects to file2.php. In normal way browsers sends previous session id to tell server which session belongs itself. Please check that you are sending this cookie while requesting file2.php