# Getting error message undefined index

Tags: php

i am new to PHP and i need to work with sessions now.
Everytime I reload the page the counter needs to go up by 1.
At first it did work but now i am getting a undefined index of 'visits' error message.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $visits = $_SESSION['visits']++;
    if ($visits == 0) {
    echo 'Je bent nieuw hier he!';
    }
    else {
    echo 'Welkom terug voor de '.$visits.' ste keer';
}
```

Comment: `$_SESSION` is not `Cookie` , sessions stores the data on server side and cookies stores the data on client side. What you are doing is working with sessions. If you re trying to make an site visits counter , then don't use sessions or cookies , use database and php , and store the counts inside the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined index with PHP sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731693/undefined-index-with-php-sessions)

Comment: @Arsh I did edit it in sessions, but it worked 1 day and now im getting the error message.

Comment: You need to define your session before you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `$_SESSION['visits']` for existence using `isset( $_SESSION['visits'] )` before actually checking `$visits` value.