# PHP session print out array other page

Tags: php

I want to print a array on a other page with sessions but it is not working

```
<?php
session_start();
$aLijst = array(1,22,55,66,99, 234,9);
$_SESSION['getallen'] = $aLijst;
?>
```

The code where i want to print it

```
<?php
session_start();
$array = $_SESSION['getallen'];
echo $array;
?>
```

Im getting a `undefined index` error

Comment: try print $_SESSION first

Comment: Your code works fine. From which files is this code taken? Where in them this code is included?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use store and use session variables across pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489365/how-to-use-store-and-use-session-variables-across-pages) Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731693/undefined-index-with-php-sessions)

Answer (score -1):

Use `print_r()` instead of echo because to print array you need to use print_r()

```
<?php
session_start();
$array = $_SESSION['getallen'];
print '<pre>';print_r($array);
?>
```