# Passing session variables into new tab

Tags: javascript, php, tabs

I am attempting to pass session variables into a new tab that gets opened in my PHP script so I can loop through the script multiple times in the same sequence.  However, the $_SESSION data appears to not be getting passed to the new tab.

Here's the code from the original tab:

```
if ($dir = opendir($filefolder)) {
        $fileCount = 0;
        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: " . $file . " " . filemtime($filefolder . $file);
            $fileInfo = new SplFileInfo($file);
            if (filemtime($filefolder . $file) > $lastcheck &&*/ $fileInfo->getExtension() == '7z') {
                copy($filefolder . $file, $workingFolder . $file);
                $_SESSION{'filename'} = $file;
                $_SESSION['filepath'] = $workingFolder . $file;
                ?>
                    <script>
                        workingWindow = window.open("<?php xecho($set->url); ?>/?module=upload&mode=automatic&step=0");
                    </script>
                <?php
                $fileCount++;   
            }
        }
```

And here is the code from the new tab:

```
$filefolder = $_SESSION['filepath'];
$filename   = $_SESSION['filename'];
$filepath   = $filefolder . $filename;
```

The error I'm getting on the new tab is:

```
Notice: Undefined index: filepath in C:\xampp\htdocs\datascrape\lib\functions\modules\upload\automatic\automaticStep0.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: filename in C:\xampp\htdocs\datascrape\lib\functions\modules\upload\automatic\automaticStep0.php on line 23
```

Comment: Is the session started? I just ask b/c if not, session variables are not yet initialized, Also if the session is not yet persisted (committed), then the new set values aren't available. This is why you need to verify your expectations on session variables first before you work with the values. Mind the concurrency of the scripts.

Comment: Yes, the session is started.  In fact, multiple sessions are started as it pulls the session start from a previous page altogether that keeps getting called on each page load.  (I realize this because I get multiple session already started notices on the page above)

Comment: And is the whole session empty in the second script? To commit the session earlier when the job is done, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php - You could try if that solves your problem, but I'm sort of guessing

Comment: Dumb question, but wouldn't session_write_close() completely end the active session?  Because I don't want to do that, since I want the user to stay logged in.  I'm just using $_SESSION since that's the only way I can think of to pass variables to a new page.  (Of course, if there's another, better way, I'd be happy to hear it. :-) )

Comment: Closing the session is different to destroying the session. The function I linked is more like "I'm done with setting session variables, I don't need it any longer for the current run of the script, free the resource" (e.g. work done). This is also important as sessions can block, so the time of blocking is shortened.

Comment: Okay, so if I'm using variables for a sequence of php scripts, and then I want to loop through that sequence of scripts multiple times, each time with a new set of session variables, should I do session_write_close at the end of each loop?  And then how do I reopen the session to the new set of session variables?

Comment: You want each time new session variables? I might not really understand. Check the manual page for session_write_close and the related functions to understand a bit more what $_SESSION has to offer and how it works. If you need to transport state via the session, It's often worth to abstract that and serialize it into the session (make it a session object), but I do not know if that is not going over your head, I can imagine this makes it easier to share it across requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $_SESSION{'filename'} = $file;
 $_SESSION['filepath'] = $workingFolder . $file;
```

Shouldnt the code to put $file into the SESSION have square brackets?

```
 $_SESSION['filename'] = $file;
 $_SESSION['filepath'] = $workingFolder . $file;
```

Comment: Oops.  Thank you for catching that.  ;-)  I just switched it to square brackets, but I still get the undefined errors, so there must be something else going on in addition to the typo.

Comment: It might have been typed in error, but in PHP you can use square and curly brackets for arrays. The curly brackets are just not so common, but the code is valid. - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing (note at the end of that section)

Comment: @EricLaRue The notice you are getting, are you assigning the $filepath and $filename inside a conditional statement. As it is only a notice it might be that they need defining outside of a conditional statement? or add the code to check that the variables are set. look at the answer to another question [Look at this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731693/undefined-index-with-php-sessions).